Need a witty alternative to "what's your problem?"
So if I've got a confrontation between two characters, and one of them is supposed to be somewhat creative and humourous, what is a witty way of putting that old provocation "what's your problem?"?
I like the sound of something to the effect of "who rubbed you the wrong way"... but it's not funny and not really provocative enough. I've currently got "who peed in your lagoon?", but to my ears, it doesn't sound like something a 'cool' character would say.
Suggested phrases don't have to be questions; in the end, I want something witty that also signals that shit's about to go down.

This sounds too vague a question with too many answers. Something like "who peed in your lagoon?" would be great for someone on a South Pacific island, but rubbish for an American office worker. Stuff like "who peed in your coffee?" is common but relates to characters who might drink coffee. You should try and find something relevant to your situation.

'Who rattled your cage?'

To rattle someone's cage:
If you rattle someone's cage, you do something to make them angry,
often on purpose.

[BBC: Learning English]
It's on point, and rather belittling (comparison with a wild animal).
who rattled your cage?

Rattling the cage is something likely to be done by children or by
childish adults, when in the presence of caged animals. The children
want to get the attention of the animal, which might be sleeping or
looking the other way, so they make the cage rattle. This usually gets
the animal's attention, and often annoys him as well.
For only the last few dozen years, expressions like "stop rattling my
cage" have become fairly common. When you rattle someone's cage, it's
not in order actually to accomplish something, it's just to annoy him
or make your presence known in a not very nice way. (It's in the same
league as "stop pulling my chain.")  SS

[Phrase Finder]

And you find that witty? And a relevant question for this list?

Synonyms for expressions are certainly on-topic unless they are exceedingly obvious.

“Witty” screams subjective to me.

Then change it to 'metaphorical alternative'.
